# Retrieve user current location using SwiftUI and MapKit

Tags: ios, swift, mobile, swiftui

I would like to know how to get the user current location using SwiftUI Framework. I have the map  displaying already but I want to know how to get the user latitude and longitude of current location. Feel free to create a class but please explain the class actions and where to implement it. 
By having the map to display already is by using the  UIViewRepresentable and the two functions called makeUIView and updateUIView
Thank you in advance

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56533059/how-to-get-current-location-with-swiftui for getting the user's current location and https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/creating-and-combining-views#compose-the-detail-view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create instance of `CLLocationManager`:

```
var locManager = CLLocationManager()
locManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
```

then get the details:

```
var currentLocation: CLLocation!

if( CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedWhenInUse ||
    CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() ==  .authorizedAlways){

  currentLocation = locManager.location

}
```

then to get longitude or latitude:

```
let longitude = currentLocation.coordinate.longitude
let latitude = currentLocation.coordinate.latitude
```

If you'd like to perform it inside a swiftUI view script, create instance:

```
@ObservedObject var locationManager = LocationManager()
```

Get them separately:

```
var userLatitude: String {
    return "\(locationManager.lastLocation?.coordinate.latitude ?? 0)"

var userLongitude: String {
        return "\(locationManager.lastLocation?.coordinate.longitude ?? 0)"
```

Comment: Can I put it inside of the let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude
            , longitude: longitude )

Comment: No, you'll have to make an instance for it first, it'll be better that way too since all you'll need to, say print it out is something like `print("Latitude: \(userLatitude) and Logitude: \(userLongitude)")`

Comment: the things is how to I put it inside the mapview

Comment: how to Crete an instance of it?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56553527/show-user-location-on-map-swiftui to put the variables I've just shown you how to get into mapView

Comment: The code that you provided plus the link that you also gave helped a lot

Comment: @Jose no problem :)

Comment: Another question, will it keep updating when the user is moving

Comment: authorisationStatus() function has deprecated by ios 14.0. It's now a property.